# $g(t)=T(\chi_{(a,t]})$, show $\|g^{\prime}\|_q = \|g\|_p $.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $1 \le p < \infty$ and define $g:[a,b] \to \mathbb{K}$ by $g(t)=T(\chi_{(a,t]})$ where $\chi_{(a,t]}$ is the characteristic function on $(a,t]$ and $T$ is a linear functional on  $X = Span\{\chi_{(a,t]} : t \in [a,b] \}$ with  $\| \cdot\|_p$. Show that $\|g^{\prime}\|_q = \|g\|_p $ where $g'$ is the derivative of $g$, $\| \cdot\|_p$ is the $p$ norm with $1/p+1/q=1$.

I was able to show that $g$ is absolutely continuous for $1 \le p < \infty$ and therefore it will be of normalized bounded variation on $[a,b]$ (as $g(a)=0$) and thus it is differentiable almost everywhere, and also that $g'$ is in $L^q[a,b]$. We have the relation $$g(t) = T(c_t) = \int_{a}^{t}g'(x)dx$$
How do I show from here that  $\|g^{\prime}\|_q = \|g\|_p $ ?